# Compatibility between strength and costrength of a monoidal monad

Tags: ct.category-theory, monoidal-categories, monads

Let $C$ be a closed monoidal category, and let $T : C \to C$ be a monad on the underlying category. Let $\sigma$ be a tensorial strength of $T$ and let $\sigma'$ be a cotensorial strength of $T$. A good reference for these notions is the paper [Logical relations for monadic types](http://arxiv.org/pdf/cs/0511006v2.pdf) by J. Goubault-Larrecq, S. Lasota, D. Nowak. It is well-known that $\sigma$ corresponds to a natural transformation

$\tau_{A,B} : \underline{\hom}(A,B) \to \underline{\hom}(T(A),T(B))),$

making $T$ a $C$-functor (at least in the case that $C$ is symmetric, see the early papers by Anders Kock). My first question is: Is it also known and written down somewhere that $\sigma'$ corresponds $1:1$ to a natural transformation

$\tau'_{A,B} : T(\underline{\hom}(A,B)) \to \underline{\hom}(A,T(B)),$

such that two certain diagrams commute? In the introduction of Kock's paper *Strong functors and monoidal monads* this is mentioned without proof.

Recall that $\sigma$ and $\sigma'$ are called compatible (so that $T$ becomes a *monoidal monad*) if the following diagrams commute.

$$\begin{matrix} A \otimes T(B) \otimes C & \xrightarrow{\sigma} & T(A \otimes B) \otimes C \\\\
\sigma' \downarrow ~ & &  ~ \downarrow \sigma' \\\\ 
A \otimes T(B \otimes C) & \xrightarrow{\sigma} & T(A \otimes B \otimes C)\end{matrix} ~~~~~~ (\heartsuit) $$

$$\begin{matrix} T(A) \otimes T(B) & \xrightarrow{\sigma} & T(T(A) \otimes B) & \xrightarrow{\sigma'} & T^2(A \otimes B) \\\\ \sigma' \downarrow ~ & & & & ~ \downarrow \mu \\\\ T(A \otimes T(B)) &  \xrightarrow{\sigma} & T^2(A \otimes B) & \xrightarrow{\mu} &  T(A \otimes B) \end{matrix} ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~(\lozenge)$$

**Question.** What are the corresponding compatibility diagrams for $\tau$ and $\tau'$? I *guess* that $(\lozenge)$ corresponds to the diagram

$$\begin{matrix} T(\underline{\hom}(T(A),T(B))) & \xrightarrow{\tau'} & \underline{\hom}(T(A),T^2(B)) \\\\
\tau \uparrow ~ & & ~ \downarrow \mu \\\\ T(\underline{\hom}(A,B)) & & \underline{\hom}(T(A),T(B)) \\\\
\tau' \downarrow ~ & & ~ \uparrow \mu \\\\
\underline{\hom}(A,T(B)) & \xrightarrow{\tau} & \underline{\hom}(T(A),T^2(B)) \end{matrix}$$

But I cannot even guess what $(\heartsuit)$ should correspond to.

Comment: Your guess about $(\lozenge)$ is correct (except that you had an extra $T$ in the bottom-left corner, which I figured was a typo so I removed it).  This can be proven using the double-categorical calculus of mates.  Would it be helpful to see it written out?  As for $(\heartsuit)$, as far as I can see it does not correspond to anything entirely in terms of $\tau$ and $\tau'$; the functors aren't composed in such a way as to allow a complete passage to mates. I think we could express it in terms of $\tau$, $\tau'$, and $\sigma'$, if that would help.